# A few questions about determining if these sets are groups or not

Tags: group-theory

I have a few questions regarding the problem in this linked image:

https://i.gyazo.com/c2dfa8cbef7f5e0642ef4f0614d5f87c.png

For part (vi), when we are thinking about the inverses of each element of that group, are we multiplying an element by its inverse or are we applying that specific operation with the inverse?

Also in part (vii), I found that x and z have two inverses. Is that fine or are they supposed to be unique to be a group? Or did I make a mistake?

Lastly, in part (viii), I'm not sure how to figure out if it has an identity? Correct me if I am wrong, but it seems that every natural number is an identity of this group, but that sounds like it is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question about (vi): You apply the specific operation that defines the group everywhere, also to inverses, the group only 'knows' that operation. In this case, you want to reach the unit, which is the number that, after applying the operation to $x$, will not change $x$. Realize that it is 1 here and not 0.

(vii): Your observation about $x$ and $z$ having two inverses is correct. Every element in a group needs to have *one* inverse, hence this is not a group.

(viii): Any number $y \in \mathbb{N}$ will be the identity (try to reason why), while a group requires to have a *unique* identity. Therefore, this also is not a group.